# Get text of span without ID

Tags: javascript, html, swift, webview, webkit

I'm trying to get a piece of text from a Span line which has not an Id. Using Xcode and Swift 3.

Here's the line:

```
<span class="name">Peter Red</span>
```

I tried this but it does not work:

```
var name = webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelector('.name').innerHTML")
        print("Name is \(name)")
```

I also tried using `.innerText`, `.textContent` and `outerText` but the console just prints `Name is ()`

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementsByClassName('name')[0]`?

Comment: `document.querySelector('.name').innerHTML` is correct for accessing the HTML of the content of the **first** span with that class as of when you run that code. So the problem is the element doesn't exist, or doesn't have that class, as of when that code runs. (Or you're misusing `evaluateJavaScript`; I have no idea about that.)

Comment: @YuvalBen-Arie: Why would that be any different? `getElementsByClassName` has worse support than `querySelector`, for one thing. But WebKit browsers definitely have `querySelector`.

Comment: You can try `document.querySelectorAll('.name')[0].innerHTML`, if it's the only one of it's class. But why can't you give it an id?

Comment: .querySelectorAll worked!! The fact is that I now get: Name is Optional(name). How can I delete "Optional"

Comment: @Albifer: I guarantee you that if `document.querySelectorAll('.name')[0].innerHTML` works, `document.querySelector('.name').innerHTML` works. Something *else* changed between your attempt with the latter and your attempt with the former.

Answer (score 0):

The [`evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript) instance method expects two parameters.

```
func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScriptString: String, 
      completionHandler: ((Any?, Error?) -> Void)? = nil)
```

You are missing the `completionHandler`, which will run once the script evaluation completes or fails.

Try the following:

```
 webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelector('.name').innerHTML") { (name, error) in
        if error == nil {
           print("Name is \(name)")
        }
    }
```